# Аналог static-maps.yandex.ru для GoogleMaps и OpenStreetMaps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api, карты, openstreetmap

Всем привет.
У Яндекс карты есть ссылка где генерируется фото по координатам, пример:

```
https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?lang=ru-RU&ll=37.5175861187,55.6427161185&size=320,320&z=12&l=map
```

Есть ли такая же ссылка для GoogleMaps и OpenStreetMaps?

Answer (score 1):

У Гугла такая фишка есть: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro?hl=ru
Но только платная она, 2 доллара за 1000 запросов.

OSM штатно вроде не имеет такого функционала. Была попытка запустить такую фишку лет 10 назад, но из-за каких-то проблем вопрос закрыли. Нужно искать сторонние реализации вроде такого: https://github.com/jperelli/osm-static-maps